# /shell-script: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: shell-script

I am getting `syntax error near unexpected token done` while executing my shell script:

```
while read filename
do
  echo "$filename"
  if [ -s $filename ]; then
    tail -10 $filename | grep `date '+%Y-%m-%d'` >> $lastlines1
    echo "- Next Error File - " >> $lastlines1
  done
  else
  echo " no errrors"
fi
```

Any ideas, where am I going wrong?

Comment: some general comments: You probably want to quote any filename variables that might possibly contain spaces.

Answer (score 5):

you are closing the while before the if.

```
while read filename 
do 
    echo "$filename" 
    if [ -s $filename ]
    then 
        tail -10 $filename | grep date '+%Y-%m-%d' >> $lastlines1 
        echo "- Next Error File - " >> $lastlines1 
    else 
        echo " no errrors" 
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's add some new lines and indentation:

```bsh
1 while read filename; do
2     echo "$filename"
3     if [ -s $filename ]; then
4         tail -10 $filename | grep date '+%Y-%m-%d' >> $lastlines1
5         echo "- Next Error File - " >> $lastlines1
6     done
7 else
8     echo " no errrors"
9 fi
```

lines 6 and 9 seem to be swapped. In other words the `while-do-done` and `if-then-else-fi` clauses are overlapping. Which is wrong in shell (and most other computer languages).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `vim` editor for scripting , it will shows text in RED if that syntax wrong

```
while read FileName 
do 
        echo "${FileName}" 

        if [ -s "${FileName}" ]; then 
            tail -10 $FileName | grep "date '+%Y-%m-%d'" >> "${lastlines1}"
            echo "- Next Error File - " >> "${lastlines1}"
        else 
            echo " no errrors" 
        fi      
done
```

Comment: `vim` won't magically fix code, just as another editor (except maybe `nano` without -w) won't break it... It does make finding syntax errors easier though... Installing `vim` on some non-Linux systems can be quite annoying...

Comment: i am not saying it will fix the code , but at least  we can notice the same. isn't it ?

Comment: It depends a lot on the user's environment. For a root user on a Linux system with internet access and a decent package manager, switching to vim is probably easy (if they can operate a vi-like editor)... Not so much for a normal user on Solaris or a user on an embedded system with limited space...

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete the `if` statement before the `do while`. If you are trying to only echo `no errors` once if no files are found, you need to use a flag to indicate it.

```
errorCount=0
while read filename 
do 
    echo "$filename" 
    if [ -s $filename ]
    then 
        tail -10 $filename | grep date '+%Y-%m-%d' >> $lastlines1 
        echo "- Next Error File - " >> $lastlines1 
        errorCount=$(($errorCount + 1))
    fi
done
if [[ $errorCount -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo " no errors"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error happens because of unexpected CR characters in file, usually because the file was generated on a Windows system which uses CR line endings. You can fix this by running `dos2unix` or `tr`, for example:

```
tr -d '\015' < yourscript.sh > newscript.sh
```

This removes any CR characters from the file and in new shell script file you didn't get that error.